# storing video for offline use with phonegap using Vimeo or Amazon?

Tags: javascript, html, video, phonegap-build, offlineapps

Currently my app allows to play videos online through `iframes` with embed links, at this moment I need that besides this, allows to download the videos for their offline visualization within the app, the video services that I have the possibility to use are Amazon and Vimeo.

For Vimeo I also have the download links of the `.mp4` files

Anyone know how can I download the videos so that they are viewable offline only from my app ?, something like Spotify with the offline playlists.

Anything would be very helpful.

Thanks